# Database Connection Check on Loading Screen

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I am Creating a app and I though of creating a loding screen with which will check the availablity of database which will use in the application if the connection to database appers to kk then then loading form will open the login form or orelse i want that form to display a error message saying network connectivity issue.

can you give give ideas on how can i work that out ?

Comment: What type of project are you using? WinForms? ASP? WPF? There are solutions to your question, but are particular to the project type you are using

Comment: @raptor i haven't tried anything first looking for idea which efficient to what i am trying to accomplish

Comment: @alex i edited the tag it's winforms and using C#

Comment: dont create a loading screen just to check DB connectivity. Splash screens should only be used if there is a lot of initialization work happening at start up. Let the application start, create a separate thread and check your db connectivity

Comment: @noviceProgrammer  yea can understand your opinion but can elaborate more on how can i work around "separate thread and check your db connectivity"

Comment: have a look at [Backgroundworker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker) class or the option of using [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.threading.tasks.task)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is not to show a loading screen while checking the connection, for 2 reasons :

1. Because usually the database connection check is done so fast that the user would not even see the loading screen, or only see a flicker of it, in which case he would be confused as to what is happening.
2. In my opinion it's not a very good practice. I would rather show a messagebox if a failure would happen. Inspired by the answer of SULFIKAR:

   ```
   Sqlconnection con=new SqlConnection();
   con.ConectionString="myconnectionstring";
   try
   {
       if(con.State==ConnectionState.Open)
       {
           con.Close();
       }
       con.Open();
       //Everything ok -> continue normally
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Database connection not available..."));//do something in case of error : exit application, log ex.Message, etc
   }
   ```

Comment: yea i agree thanks for the help i also think this way it's better

Answer (score 1):

```
Sqlconnection con=new SqlConnection();
con.ConectionString="myconnectionstring";
try
{
  if(con.State==ConnectionState.Open)
   {
    con.Close();
   }
   con.Open();
    //Success message
}
catch(Exception)
{
  //Failure Message
}
```

Comment: How does this relate? Please provide explanation

Comment: This code helps to verify the availability of back end.

Comment: how about loading screen part ?